# Norm, convexity and composition of functions

Tags: functional-analysis

> Claim 1: {convex and non-decreasing func.} ◦ {convex func.} is convex

> Claim 2: Norms are convex (The triangle inequality is the same thing as convexity of the norm)

> Claim 3: {convex and non-decreasing func.} ◦ {metric} is probably not a metric (or, {**concave** and non-decreasing func.} ◦ {metric} is still a metric)

I've seen proof of each of these claims[[1](https://www.stat.cmu.edu/%7Eryantibs/convexopt-F18/scribes/Lecture_3.pdf), [2](https://www.math.uh.edu/%7Edlabate/PagesfromAnalysis.pdf), [3.1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1241567/if-varrho-is-a-metric-and-phi-is-concave-then-is-phi-circ-varrho-also), [3.2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4292306/if-f-is-strictly-convex-and-d-a-metric-then-f-circ-d-is-a-metric)]. However, claim 3 seems unexpected under the context of 1 and 2. How can I make sense of this?

Comment: Very minor comment: For the "probably not a metric" and "still a metric", you probably want to add the condition that your convex/concave and non-decreasing function $f$ satisfies $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)>0$ for all $x>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say we have a vector space $X$ and a function $p:X\to \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $p(ax)=|a|p(x)$ for all $a\in \mathbb{R}$ and $x\in X$, and such that $p(x)=0$ iff $x=0$.

Then $p$ satisfies the triangle inequality (and is therefore a norm) iff it's a convex function. This is where our connection between the triangle inequality and convexity come from. This is why we might expect $f(\|\cdot\|)$ to be a metric, because by $1$ and $2$, it's convex. So it should satisfy triangle inequality, right?

But the proof that $p$ satisfies triangle inequality iff it's convex uses the positive homogeneity. **Note: $p$ actually satisfies something stronger than positive homogeneity: It is positive homogeneous and symmetric/balanced. By symmetric/balanced, we mean that $p(ax)=p(|a|x)$ for any scalar $a$ and any vector $x$. So we have assumed something more than positive homogeneity, but in our connections below, we actually will only use the positive homogeneity, in that we will only pull positive (or at least non-negative) scalars out of $p$.**

If $p$ satisfies the triangle inequality, we have $$p(\theta x+(1-\theta)y)\leqslant p(\theta x)+p((1-\theta)y)=\theta p(x)+(1-\theta)p(y).$$ The second step where we pull the $\theta, 1-\theta$ out of $p$ uses positive homogeneity.

On the other hand, if $p$ is convex, we fix $x,y\neq 0$ and note that \begin{align*}p(x+y) & = (p(x)+p(y))p\Bigl(\frac{p(x)}{p(x)+p(y)} \cdot \frac{x}{p(x)}+\frac{p(y)}{p(x)+p(y)}\cdot \frac{y}{p(y)}\Bigr) \\ & \leqslant (p(x)+p(y))\Bigl(\frac{p(x)}{p(x)+p(y)}\cdot \frac{p(x)}{p(x)} + \frac{p(y)}{p(x)+p(y)}\cdot \frac{p(y)}{p(y)}\Bigr) \\ & = p(x)+p(y).\end{align*} We used positive homogeneity several times here to pull $p(x), p(y), p(x)+p(y)$ outside of $p$.

If we drop positive homogeneity (say $p(x)=\|x\|^2$, where $\|\cdot\|$ is some existing norm), then repeating the calculation above yields that $$p(x+y)\leqslant (p(x)+p(y))^2 \Bigl(\frac{p(x)}{p(x)+p(y)}\cdot \frac{p(x)}{p(x)^2}+\frac{p(y)}{p(x)+p(y)}\cdot \frac{p(y)}{p(y)^2}\Bigr).$$ That's because we now have $p(ax)=a^x2 p(x)$, so things get squared when we pull them outside of $p$. But this inequality isn't useful to see triangle inequality. Similarly, we could try $\frac{\sqrt{p(x)}}{\sqrt{p(x)}+\sqrt{p(y)}}$ as our first weight, which would yield $p(x)/p(x)$ and $p(y)/p(y)$ terms, but this only leads to triangle inequality on $\sqrt{p}=\|\cdot\|$ again.

So my summary for why $f(\|\cdot\|)$ isn't a metric even though it's convex (when $f$ is convex, non-decreasing, and $f(x)=0$ iff $x=0$) is that our familiar pairing of convexity and triangle inequality needs the positive homogeneity, which $f$ typically will not have.

EDIT: Through frequent association, we often associate convexity with the triangle inequality (for checking that a quasi-seminorm is a seminorm, for example). So the question asks: If convexity goes hand in hand with triangle inequality, we would expect convexity-preserving compositions to preserve triangle inequality, and $g\mapsto f\circ g$ is convexity-preserving when $f$ is convex and non-decreasing. But actually it turns out that we want $f$ to be **concave** and non-decreasing. Why?

When I read the question, I was stumped. After thinking about it for a bit, here's what I've come up with. The heuristic: We want **subaddtivity** preservation, not convexity preservation. It is a special property of norms (specifically, it uses positive homogeneity) that convexity implies subadditivity for a norm. But that's kind of a fluke, special to the case of a norm as opposed to other metrics. It's only in the special case of positive homogeneity that we get the convexity-subadditivity connection.

For a set $X$ and a function $\rho:X\times X\to \mathbb{R}^+$, $\rho$ satisfies the triangle inequality if for all $x,y,z\in X$, $\rho(x,z)\leqslant \rho(x,y)+\rho(y,z)$.

What conditions do we need to place on a function $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}^+$ to get that for any $X$ and any $\rho:X\times X\to \mathbb{R}^+$ satisfying the triangle inequality, $f\circ \rho$ also satisfies the triangle inequality?

> Claim: If $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}^+$ is subadditive and non-decreasing, then for any $X$ and any $\rho:X\times X\to \mathbb{R}^+$ satisfying the triangle inequality, $f\circ \rho$ also satisfies the triangle inequality.

Proof: Assume that $f$ is subadditive and non-decreasing. Assume that $X$ is a set and $\rho:X\times X\to \mathbb{R}^+$ satisfies the triangle inequality. Fix any $x,y,z\in X$. Then $$f(\rho(x,z)) \leqslant f(\rho(x,y)+\rho(y,z))\leqslant f(\rho(x,y))+f(\rho(y,z)).$$   The first inequality uses that $f$ is non-decreasing, the second uses subadditivity.

We have a partial converse: Assume that $f$ is not subadditive. There exist $a,b\in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $f(a)+f(b)<f(a+b)$. Define $\rho:\mathbb{R}^+\times\mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}^+$ by $\rho(x,y)=|x-y|$. Then take $x=0$, $y=a$, and $z=a+b$. $$f(\rho(x,z))=f(a+b)>f(a)+f(b)=f(\rho(x,y))+f(\rho(y,z)).$$

If $X$ is a vector space and $d:X\times X\to \mathbb{R}^+$ is a symmetric, translation invariant function (that is, $f(u,v)=f(v,u)$ and $f(u,v)=f(u+w,v+w)$ for all $u,v,w\in X$), then $d$ satisfies the triangle inequality if and only if $D(x):=d(0,x)$ is subadditive. In the case that we start with an absolutely homogeneous functional $p:X\to \mathbb{R}^+$ and ask if it's a seminorm, and then try to build a pseudometric out of it, the pseudometric candidate $d(x,y)$ is given by $d(x,y)=p(x-y)$, and then $D(x)=p(x)$ again. But the fact above regarding $d$ and $D$ is true, even without absolute homogeneity.

If we start with our symmetric, translation invariant $d$, then asking that the operation $d\mapsto f\circ d$ preserves the triangle inequality is equivalent to asking that $D\mapsto f\circ D$ preserve subadditivity.

An aside: If $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}^+$ is concave, then it is non-decreasing. To see this, note that if $0\leqslant a<b$ are such that $f(a)>f(b)$, then the function $g(x)=f(x+a)-f(a)$ is concave, satisfies $g(0)=0$, and satisfies $g(b-a)<0$. For $0<\theta<1$, \begin{align*} g(b-a) & = g(\theta \theta^{-1}(b-a)) = g(\theta \theta^{-1}(b-a)+(1-\theta)0)) \geqslant \theta g(\theta^{-1}(b-a))+(1-\theta)g(0) \\ & =\theta g(\theta^{-1}(b-a)).\end{align*} Therefore $$g(b-a)/\theta \geqslant g(\theta^{-1}(b-a)).$$  Letting $\theta$ approach $0$ from the right says that $\lim_{x\to\infty} g(x)=-\infty$. But this contradicts our original assumption that $f$ takes only non-negative values. This argument becomes much simpler if we assume differentiable, because then concavity says $f'$ is decreasing. If $f$ decreases at all, ever, then it decreases at least that fast forever, and therefore cannot stay positive forever.

Back to the question: If $f:\mathbb{R}^+\to \mathbb{R}^+$ is concave (and therefore non-decreasing), and $f(0)=0$, then $f$ is subadditive. This is mentioned in the comments here and proved in the linked questions in the original post. For the sake of having a complete answer here, I will repeat it.

Fix $x,y>0$. Then \begin{align*} f(x)+f(y) & = f\Bigl(\frac{x}{x+y}\cdot (x+y)+\frac{y}{x+y}\cdot 0\Bigr) \\ & + f\Bigl(\frac{y}{x+y}\cdot (x+y)+\frac{x}{x+y}\cdot 0\Bigr) \\ & \geqslant \frac{x}{x+y}f(x+y)+0+\frac{y}{x+y}f(x+y)+0\\ & =f(x+y).\end{align*} Here we're implicitly using that concave and $f(0)=0$ imply $f(\theta x)\geqslant \theta f(x)$, which doesn't come up at all for the positive homogeneous case, because we just pull $\theta$ out in that case.

On the other hand, if $p$ is a convex, positive homogeneous, non-negative functional on $X$ (and if $p(u)+p(v)>0$), then we have \begin{align*} p(u+v)& = (p(u)+p(v)+2\epsilon) p\Bigl(\frac{p(u)+\epsilon}{p(u)+p(v)+2\epsilon}\cdot \frac{u}{p(u)+\epsilon} + \frac{p(v)+\epsilon}{p(u)+p(v)+2\epsilon} \cdot \frac{v}{p(v)+\epsilon}\Bigr) \\ & \leqslant (p(u)+\epsilon)p\Bigl(\frac{u}{p(u)+\epsilon}\Bigr)+(p(v)+\epsilon)p\Bigl(\frac{v}{p(v)+\epsilon}\Bigr) \\ & < (p(u)+\epsilon)(1)+(p(v)+\epsilon)(1)\\ & = p(u)+p(v)+2\epsilon.\end{align*} Taking the limit as $\epsilon\to 0^+$ gives the triangle inequality. We added the $\epsilon$ to avoid dividing by zero in the trivial case that $u=v=0$.

So we can see that, in addition to using positive homogeneity frequently, the proof of subadditivity of $f$ from concavity represents $x$ and $y$, separately, as convex combinations of $x+y$ and $0$. The proof of subadditivity of $p$ from convexity of $p$ (roughly speaking) represents $x+y$ and convex combinations of $[p(u)+p(v)]u$ and $[p(u)+p(v)]v$. So the way that concavity/convexity are used within the arguments are kind of reverses of each other.

Comment: Very good answer thank you! Here are some notes for the potential audience: positive homogeneity (of degree 1) means f(ax) = af(x) when a, x positive. Also, some recommended readings are Lp's wiki [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space) for p>1 and 0<p<1 cases.

Comment: Another question is, why {concave} ◦ {metric} (which is concave) remains a metric (heuristic explanation is preferred). I understand that the subadditivity of concave functions completes the proof, but we've agreed that norms should be convex to induce a metric. How come concave function can also induce metric now?

Comment: I really like this question. When I first read it, I completely agree that it was the opposite of my intuition. That being said, I have attempted to provide both a heuristic explanation, as well as a quick look "under the hood" to see what the difference is. Since this was all brand new to me as I was writing it, it is probably long and rambling.

Comment: Excellence explanation. The inverse argument is inspiring. Some online materials like to make conditions more than sufficient to simplify the arguments for first-time readers and things don’t add up under scrutiny. I also abused the terminology “induce”, readers may refer to textbooks for meticulous definitions for norms and metrics. Thank you for your work!

Comment: Thank you. And thank you for the question.